# What is the keras sample_weights values range?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I tried to use normalized values (sum 1) for the keras sample_weights and the model accuracy got much worse.

So, to investigate this, I tried to use a small fixed value for the sample_weights setting it at 0.001 for all the samples expecting no difference at all but the accuracy was much worse than setting all of them to 1.
Setting all of them to 100 made no difference over the all 1 baseline.

What am I doing wrong, is there a preferred range for these values, like greater than 1?